# Context based search in JSP

Tags: html, jsp, html-select

I have a strange issue with the
`<Select><option/></select>` 
tag.I don't write any code to enable context search(ie. if I type A it will list all possible combinations with A like AA,Aa,Ab,AB,Ac,AC and so on(not in the same order)).Similarly if I type Ab it should list all combinations starting with Ab which it does but the problem is you have to be little quick here otherwise if I press A and wait some time and then press B then I wil get all contents starting with B and not with AB which is what was intented.Is there an alternate to this so that whatever I type will get the apt search results

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is a behavior provided by the browser (and/or plugin(s) user may have installed), therefore if may differ for different clients.
In order to have a consistent customizable behavior you'll need to replace standard <select> with JS-based component. Look at [ExtJS](http://extjs.com/products/extjs/) ComboBox implementation for example; there are many others available as well.