# Optimizing Select Tag in HTML

Tags: html-select

This is in a way a repeat of my previous question here.
[Context based search in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107944/context-based-search-in-jsp)

I got a reply to look at this site [Ext JS](http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/combos.html)

I actually want a combo box like the Transformed Select in that Page.I tried it offline but it behaves as a normal combo box.Is it done using css? Can anyone help me in developing a similar combo box.

Answer (score 0):

Have you linked to a CSS file like the one in the demo.

Edit:

They have 4 CSS files included in the page.

http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/form/combos.css

http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/shared/examples.css

http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/resources/css/ext-all.css

http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/resources/css/xtheme-gray.css

Locate the classes defined and copy the appropriate classes and make a new file named

YouFile.css

and paste these classes inside the file and make a reference to the created CSS file from your page.

Comment: Thanks for that...Appreciate your time

Comment: I am still not able to get the actual functionality.I am not worried about the design.I just want that box to wait till I type the next letter which is not happening.